# How to get all divs below on 1-level with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

$('#masterDiv div') gets me all the divs below the masterDiv and divs nested in these divs. How to get only 1-level children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this `$('#masterDiv > div')`.

It is [Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#masterDiv").children("div")
```

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#masterDiv').children('div')
```